# How to build an RDD where each element equals a sum of preceding input elements?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a list of numbers in RDD collection. From this list I need to create another RDD list where each element equals the sum of all preceding to it elements. How to build such an RDD in Spark?

The following Scala code gives an illustration of what I am trying to achieve in Spark:

```
object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val lst: List[Float] = List(1, 2, 3)
    val result = sum(List(), 0, lst)
    println(result)
  }

  def sum(acc: List[Float], runningSum: Float, list: List[Float]): List[Float] = {
    list match {
      case List() => acc.reverse
      case List(x, _*) => {
        val newSum = runningSum + x
        sum(newSum :: acc, newSum, list.tail)
      }

    }
  }
```

Running this results in:

```
List(1.0, 3.0, 6.0)
```

What would be an equivalent Spark code for this example?

Comment: You can't really do this with an RDD (at least, not in a way that gains the advantages of an RDD); the whole point of an RDD is to process parts of it in parallel, whereas in your case elements of the new list depend on every element of the original list.

Comment: Understood, but I still have to compute this sum from RDD. What would you do in this case?

Comment: Ideally, `.collect()` the RDD and compute the sum locally, and then `sc.parallelize` again if need be. If it's too big to fit in memory, all I can think of is to figure out some way of knowing which elements are "earlier" than others (perhaps by giving each an index), `cartesian` the RDD with itself to get all possible pairs of elements, `filter` out those pairs where the second entry is "after" the first, and then `aggregateByKey` to do the summing. It'll work, but it's definitely going to be slow.

Answer (score 0):

So this is something which is a bit tricky to do in Spark, but one option would be to do a mapPartitionsWithIndex and compute the sum of each partition and then collect the result back to your driver program. You could then use this and do another mapPartitionsWithIndex and compute the sum using the sum of the previous partitions as the starting point and then continue adding the elements from this point forward. This will be somewhat slow, but we don't need to depend on collect or bringing all of the elements back to the driver.

e.g.

```
val c = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex((f, i) => List((f, i.sum)).iterator).collect()
val sumRdd = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{(f, i) => 
  val previousElem = c.filter(_._1 < f).map(_._2).sum
  var e = previousElem
  i.map{ ne =>
    val ret = e
    e = e + ne
    ret
   }}
```

Comment: You still use `collect`... Anyway, from reading this code  it is it is mind-boggingly hard to understand what solution rteally tries to achieve. All advantages of functional code clarity are lost, I am afraid.

Comment: we still use collect, however we collect a much smaller number of elements back to the driver. This solution has the benefit of working with datasets which are too large to fit on a single machine, which is probably why you are working in Spark, but it certainly is less clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem as others mention is that RDDs don't have a notion of ordering, so you'll have to provide your definition for "all preceding to it elements" as part of the input, for instance, as lines:

`1 1.0
2 3.0
3 7.0`

I'm assuming, of course, that there is no way you can load your list in memory on the driver. Given your type of problem, I'm afraid there is no trivial solution, But I'll do my best to outline one.

Your problem basically requires a sequential read, but you can do it in smaller chunks. For instance, you can partition your list on chunks of 10000 items  by calling `map(x => (x._1%10000, x._1, x._2))`. The actual number you can tweak based on your memory constraints.

Then, you can put all items from a given sublist together by using the `groupByKey()` method. This puts the entire sublist on your hands on a given executor, in memory.

Then you can proceed to sort and compute your resulting sub-list as you do with the `sum()` method on your example. This would give you a tuple with the bucket order, sum and list:

`(1,3270,List(17, 12, 15)`

This RDD you can map into two others, first, map to just (1,3271) to get the sum for the sublist. Second, map to (1, 17), (1,12)... tuples, which you can persist.

The first map you can collect (it is very small, as is only 1 tuple per 10000 values). Once on the driver, sort and sum to get the total sum for ALL previous sub-lists. Put this back as a new RDD and then you can do a `join` with the second RDD above. Then you can add the total sum for the bucket (global) to the total sums in the sub-list (local), and then you can store all the results back to disk.

In general, what I'm describing is a divide-and-conquer approach. Basically turn your list on a list of lists, where every smaller list fits in memory.